# MySQL join: return at first match

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables in a mySQL database and I want to do a join on them. Imagine both of them have 3000 entries. When mySQL executes the query, it will return 3000*3000 possible rows. I would like to run the query on one table and return each row as soon as it finds a match in the second table (so if it finds a matching row in row number two of t2, it can skip the other possibile combinations). For example, this would be something like this

select * from t1 where *at least one match*(t1.id = t2.id)

Is there any way in mySQL to do this?

I am aware that usually such joins should be avoided, but in this case I do not have alternatives.

Comment: Please post the structure of both tables so we can envision their relationship. With proper join condition, you probably should not be getting 3000^2 rows back (which is what you would get with _no_ join condition)

Comment: The trick may be to join against a derived table that returns a `MIN()` aggregate on some column in `t2`. Need to see the column lists though...

Comment: You haven't really offered up much in terms of an explanation of your table schema to help in provide advice.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need rows from the first table (it's not clear, but your example implies this), you may be able to do this without a `JOIN` by using an `EXISTS` condition. Something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_x
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table_y
              WHERE table_x.id = table_y.id)
```

[Here's the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) for this feature.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a good use for a left join.

```
SELECT T1.*, T2.*
FROM t1 
LEFT JOIN t2 on T1.Pk_ID = T2.FK_ID
```

if the ID's are indexed in both tables there's no reason the results shouldn't return in fractions of a second.

using a Cartesian is when the 3000*3000 takes effect but by joining the Cartesian is nearly eliminated.  Evidence of this is in the explain plan of the SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for EXISTS clause:

```
SELECT * FROM t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM t2 WHERE t1.ID = t2.ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also consider this example (although I suspect that those already provided are more efficient)...

```
SELECT * FROM ints;
+---+
| i |
+---+
| 0 |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |
| 7 |
| 8 |
| 9 |
+---+

SELECT * FROM ints x JOIN ints y ON y.i = 10;

SELECT x.* FROM ints x JOIN ints y ON y.i = 9;
+---+
| i |
+---+
| 0 |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |
| 7 |
| 8 |
| 9 |
+---+
```